# Not passing correct value from dropdown list to trigger javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core

I have a drop down list which holds the values "3 Week View", "Six Week View", "Twelve Week View". This drop down list is then used to trigger a javascript function based on selected value. The issue I am having is it is only passing the value of "three" regardless of what dropdown item I select. Its probably something obvious I have just never done this before.

```
HTML
<center>View:</center>
                <select class="form-control" id="myList" onchange="funSelectView(this.value)">
                    <option value="none" id="df">Please Select</option>
                    <option value="three" id="thw">3 Week</option>
                    <option value="six" id="sw">6 week</option>
                    <option value="twelve" id="tww">12 Week</option>
                </select>
```

```
Javascript
function funSelectView() {
        document.getElementById("myList").onchange = function () {
            var sheet = document.getElementById("myList").value;
            if (sheet === "three") {
                alert(value);
                funThreeWeekView();
            }
            if (sheet === "six") {
                alert(value);
                funSixWeekView();
            }
            if (sheet === "twelve") {
                alert(value);
                funTwelveWeekView();
            }
            if (sheet === "none") {
                hideAll();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you run the `onchange` twice and you never set the value of the variable named `value` used in the alerts.

Answer (score 0):

In this cases, I usually prefer two methods below. You have also used, but you have mixed
them. I am showing below.
First:

Html

```
<center>View:</center>
<select class="form-control" id="myList" onchange="funSelectView(this.value)">
    <option value="none" id="df">Please Select</option>
    <option value="three" id="thw">3 Week</option>
    <option value="six" id="sw">6 week</option>
    <option value="twelve" id="tww">12 Week</option>
</select>
```

Javascript

```
function funSelectView(value){
    if (value === "three") {
        alert(value);
        // funThreeWeekView(); // I don't know about it method
    }
    if (value === "six") {
        alert(value);
        // funSixWeekView();
    }
    if (value === "twelve") {
        alert(value);
        // funTwelveWeekView();
    }
    if (value === "none") {
        hideAll();
    }
}
```

Second:

Html

```
<center>View:</center>
<select class="form-control" id="myList">
    <option value="none" id="df">Please Select</option>
    <option value="three" id="thw">3 Week</option>
    <option value="six" id="sw">6 week</option>
    <option value="twelve" id="tww">12 Week</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("myList").onchange = function () {
    var sheet = document.getElementById("myList").value;
    if (sheet === "three") {
        alert(sheet);
        funThreeWeekView();
    }
    if (sheet === "six") {
        alert(sheet);
        funSixWeekView();
    }
    if (sheet === "twelve") {
        alert(sheet);
        funTwelveWeekView();
    }
    if (sheet === "none") {
        hideAll();
    }
}
```